# Paypal login freeze (opencart 2.1.0.2)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I added the option to login with Paypal.
I am using the Paypal standard login.

I am using sandbox for testing but the issue persists even if in real mode.

Everything is ok except after the login with the email of paypal, after I input the credentials of paypal account it goes to load the setting from paypal account that I selected (name, date of birth etc,) it goes ok and after that it freezes in the same login window (a blank window).

In the site it does not do anything and doesn't login.
I noticed that the url in the login window goes to the redirect that I had to configure. I think that maybe it's related with the redirect URL. Can anyone please check if everything is ok with the settings or if it is a known bug with this?

The full url that appears in the login windows after the credencials are submitted is:

https://www.quitandabrasil.com/index.php?route=module/pp_login/login&scope=address+profile+email+phone&code=nhZpJ2YmnH_R3HXkheGFfPErrJluZ-fDhfDFuPgqLzwYX1AmNYNEfbjPiT5D-46YO-LaPWLQU98CVEoWO5ndUMfC1XGWOMg_yAJ6ZYCK_EpC1ns4Crl6A5bDV1DdAbrTbJlRthHtbpM1NAVBJpxskbViJjGhgdczvInmmSg8BCdEupPDJzKCb2j9RLoKZl8EEeD0pVBov2zRjrq2

I have uploaded pics of the opencart config "login with paypal" and from the developer site that have the sandbox account.

[DGjlR.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGjlR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/3640

Change the API URLs

//$endpoint = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token';

$endpoint = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice';

//$endpoint = 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token';
$endpoint = 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice';

Comment/remove line:
//CURLOPT_USERPWD => $this->config->get('pp_login_client_id') . ':' . $this->config->get('pp_login_secret'),